# Show Selected item on context menu header

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have created an application for Android that has an activity that has a `ListView` which lists all playlists.

I have added a `ContextMenu`, so that a long-click brings up several options such as "Delete", "Play", etc.

In the `ContextMenu` handler, how can I extract information to know which playlist the context menu has been clicked for.

Here I want to display the selected playlist name on context menu header.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,
                                 View v,
                                 ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
{

     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Selected Playlist Name");      
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Play");     
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 1, "Delete"); 
}
```

Comment: Chirag, when you create a ContextMenu you should already have selected a playlist, as shown by your line menu.setHeaderTitle("Selected Playlist Name").  If you didn't, what would you be playing or deleting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to get the text in the selected item in the ListView. You can read the information from the `AdapterContextMenuInfo` when you cast `menuInfo` to the type `AdapterContextMenuInfo` and then read the value from the property `targetView`)

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
   AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
   String name = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
   menu.setHeaderTitle(name);      
   menu.add(0,v.getId(), 0, "Play");    
   menu.add(0,v.getId(), 1, "Delete"); 
}
```